# _Unchecked_uninitialized_move???? c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I get the following two error messages when I compile the below code for a console application.  Please help.  I don't understand the error messages.  I'm running Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.  When I double click on the error messages, it takes me to the vector include file.

```
error C2039: '_Unchecked_uninitialized_move' : is not a member of 'stdext'
error C3861: '_Unchecked_uninitialized_move': identifier not found
error C2039: '_Unchecked_uninitialized_move' : is not a member of 'stdext'
error C3861: '_Unchecked_uninitialized_move': identifier not found
```

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int scores[] = {70,80,90,100};
  vector<int> scorePercent (scores, scores + sizeof(scores) / sizeof(int) );

  cout << endl;
  cin.get();
}
```

Contents of `stdafx.h`:

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
// #pragma once
#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
```

Comment: What is `scores + sizeof(scores) / sizeof(int)` supposed to do?

Comment: Please paste in the contents of stdafx.h

Comment: @ChaosPandion, no, this is the two-iterator constructor (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/). Here the iterator is a pointer type, which is a perfectly good forward iterator.

Comment: The error doesnt seem to be in the code you have posted.Probably this will work just fine without the `stdafx.h`.

Comment: The only thing I can think of here is something in stdafx.h is breaking the STL includes (maybe it's defining a header guard or something?). Other than that, it's a broken compiler.

Comment: scores + sizeof(scores) / sizeof(int) is supposed to define the beginning and end of the vector.

Comment: Is it possible that some include files are out of date?  I'm running Visual Studio 2008...

Comment: @JerryCarson, please post stdafx.h first, so we can definitively exclude the possibility that there might be something wrong there

Comment: // stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>



// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here

Comment: @JerryCarson, please edit into the question in the future, comments are not designed for multi-line pastes. Is that all there is, though?

Comment: what is in targetver.h ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to be correct; something appears to be wrong with your compiler or compiler settings. Try recreating the project; if that fails, run a repair install, or uninstall and reinstall the compiler.